# how to convert strings like "this is an example" to "this-is-an-example" under ruby

Tags: ruby

How do I convert strings like "this is an example" to "this-is-an-example" under ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to make something that is a good URL slug, there are lots of ways to do it.

Generally, you want to remove everything that is not a letter or number, and then replace all whitespace characters with dashes.

So:

```
s = "this is an 'example'"
s = s.gsub(/\W+/, ' ').strip
s = s.gsub(/\s+/,'-')
```

At the end `s` will equal `"this-is-an-example"`

I used the source code from a ruby testing library called [contest](http://github.com/citrusbyte/contest/tree/master) to get this particular way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest version:

```
"this is an example".tr(" ", "-")
#=> "this-is-an-example"
```

You could also do something like this, which is slightly more robust and easier to extend by updating the regular expression:

```
"this is an example".gsub(/\s+/, "-")
#=> "this-is-an-example"
```

The above will replace all chunks of white space (any combination of multiple spaces, tabs, newlines) to a single dash.

See the [String class reference](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html) for more details about the methods that can be used to manipulate strings in Ruby.

If you are trying to generate a string that can be used in a URL, you should also consider stripping other non-alphanumeric characters (especially the ones that have special meaning in URLs), or replacing them with an alphanumeric equivalent ([example](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html#M001367), as suggested by Rob Cameron in his answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rails take a look at `parameterize()`, it does exactly what you're looking for:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html#M001367

```
foo = "Hello, world!"
foo.parameterize => 'hello-world'
```

Comment: cheers mate, that is exactly what I want to, but it seems not working with Unicode and it turns out "parameterize" method not found here